# Rows disappears from SQL Server Table after Insert and Commit

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-insert, commit

I have a SQL Server table with only one column and below is the query I use to insert data. I always "COMMIT TRAN" after the row has been inserted, but the newly added row disappears a few days after I inserted/commit tran. I have never had this issue with any other table and I use these transaction statements often. Any anyone help as to why this keeps happening with this table?

Here is the query I run:

```
Begin tran
    insert into ur77_licensee ([licensee name])
    values ('8210 - J.Crew')

    select * 
    from ur77_licensee
    where [licensee name] like '%8210%'

commit tran
```

Comment: It was deleted. Simple as that. I would check: 1) trigger 2) jobs 3) application 4)ask other users that have access to that table

Comment: maybe you have a cascade delete from another table. Maybe there's a job deleting it. maybe someone deleted it.

Comment: No other user makes changes to this table. How do I check trigger, jobs, application?  Can you help clarify? I'm somewhat new to SQL so any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to build some kind of audit system which would be quite a challenge. Your code is not causing the delete.  My guess is there is some kind of maintenance job doing it, but who knows? I would:

- change the permissions on the table to only allow a specific user to make changes
- make your code use that user
- wait for somebody to come complain about how they can no longer delete

If everybody is running as an admin, well.. that's why you don't have everybody run as admin!

Alternatively you could:

- create a delete trigger.  When an item is deleted have it insert into a delete table, that would at least let you seen *when* it happened.